# How to refresh tablesorter when rows are added?

Tags: python, ajax, bootstrap-4, reload, tablesorter

I'm loading in background task (using ajax and Python api) a possibly large table by blocks of 25 rows.  I'm using a bootstrap table sorter.  I would like to be able to initialise table sorter after first block loaded and then refresh it after each block.

If I simply initialise my table sorter on the first block loaded, filter and sort, it fails when a subsequent block is loaded.

Is there a way to refresh/reload table sorter as soon as rows are added?

Comment: Which table sorting addon are you using? Have you tried using a pager? And please share the code you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,
I finaly did it using following syntax:
 $("#my-table").trigger("update", [resort, dummyCallbackFunction]);

Where resort is a boolean set to True or False and dummyCallFunction a function doing nothing in my case.

It works perfectly.